# rules of inference, language into metalanguage

Tags: logic, deduction, natural-deduction

There are rules of inference, e.g. in natural deduction they are listed.
These rules follow the same rules than the logic language.
If we see Modus ponens,

> a → b, a ⊢ b

We can write for the same purpose,

> ((a → b) ∧ a) → b.

So, I don't understand what we gained by constructing the inference rules.

I guess that the switch from premises in logic language to the conclusion has to do with Metalanguage.

For example if we write

> p ⊢ p,

what was said?

Comment: You can type unicode ⊫ ⊢
∨ ∧ →

Comment: And yes, they are "recipes" in the meta-language. They are written as [schema](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/) because they instruct us how to manipulate formulas of the object language.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA the first p is a premise and the second is the conclusion

Comment: @Rushi I am typing with a phone and don't know how to use Unicode

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you write "to manipulate formula las". But I don't understand, formulas are defined by the operators, and, or, not, imply, etc. And the operators are defined by themselves. Moreover , if I write p, this says that p himself is true. May be that to say it's true is a false assumption, but the language contains in himself the content of "truthness".

Comment: Just find it via google and copy paste it (To start with). Also how did you type →? You have that on your phone?

Comment: Ive typed what I imagine you want to say as Unicode. But I am not sure what it is! Please check and change

Comment: @Rushi yes. the sign ^ if you make a long typing shows you the options ↑←↓→

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntactical specifications of the language of propositional logic allows us to build formulae from propositional variables : **p, q**, ... and constants : **⊥,⊤** using the *propositional connectives*: **¬,∨,∧,→**.

Thus, **p → q** is a formula, while, e.g. **p+q** is not.

With the symbol: **α, φ ⊢ ψ** we mean that the formula **ψ** is *derivable* in the propositional calculus from the premises **α, φ**, i.e. that starting with the premise we can "produce" the conclusion using a finite number of applications of rules of inference, like *modus ponens*.

The symbol **φ ⊢ ψ** is not a formula, but it expresses a relation between formulae of the calculus; **⊢** is **not** a symbol of the language: it is not present in the syntactical specifications above.

The statements in the metalanguage express "facts" about the language and the calculus, and thus are not formulae of the language.

[Rules of inference](https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/#H4) are necessary in order to "transform" formulae in input (the premises) into formulae in output: the conclusion.

They are "recipes" in the metalanguage, written as schema exactly because they instruct us how to manipulate formulae.

The symbol **p ⊢ p** expresses the fact (intuitively quite obvious) that from  premise **p** we can derive the conclusion **p**.

Comment: Thanks so much @Mauro. It's exactly my problem..

Comment: @kouty - you are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You write

> We can write for the same purpose,
>
> > ((a → b) ∧ a) → b

This is not accurate. What we really mean to write is

> ⊢ ((a → b) ∧ a) → b

In longer form

> ((a → b) ∧ a) → b

is just a term in logic, exactly like

1. a → b
2. a

are terms.
Whereas

> ⊢ ((a → b) ∧ a) → b

is a **metalanguage claim** about that term which could be long-form-articulated as

> The term '((a → b) ∧ a) → b' is a tautology.

IOW the '⊢' is a crucial jump from the metalanguage into the object-language.